# how to implement i18n use spring mvc use url rather than param in get request？

Tags: spring, internationalization

Most tutorials are implemented by GET request like this: www.xxx.com.index?lang=en-US.

I want to get a solution like this：[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/index][1].

The locale("en-US") is after domain.

And I also don't want to modify the existing controller.

Comment: Why would you need to modify the controller? There is an interceptor not a controller. you will need to implement your own `LocaleChangeInterceptor` (or whatever you want to call it). Or use URL rewriting to extract the `/en-us/` part and make it (internally) a parameter and forward to a non `/en-us`/ URL.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The URLs of my website is like /{language}/article/{articleName}, I want all requests from the browser to contain {language}, so I change the request mapping of the controller. but I try my best to search solution and implement LocaleChangeInterceptor but failed. Do you have any solution about implement LocaleChangeInterceptor?

Comment: Use URL rewriting to transform the URL into something else (with a parameter) so that you can use whatever you want. That way your external and internal (for lack of a beter comparison) are different but you don't need to change the controllers each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it. The solution is to implement `LocaleChangeInterceptor`,
The preHandle Method of this class in spring is:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws ServletException {
    String newLocale = request.getParameter(this.paramName);
    if (newLocale != null && this.checkHttpMethod(request.getMethod())) {
        LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
        if (localeResolver == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No LocaleResolver found: not in a DispatcherServlet request?");
        }

        localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, StringUtils.parseLocaleString(newLocale));
    }

    return true;
}
```

My preHandle Method of it:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws ServletException {
    if (this.checkHttpMethod(request.getMethod())) {
        LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
        if (localeResolver == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No LocaleResolver found: not in a DispatcherServlet request?");
        }

        localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, I18nUtil.getLocaleByUrl(request.getServletPath()));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Just implement `I18nUtil.getLocaleByUrl(request.getServletPath())`.
Thank you very much!@M. Deinum